# Does the Lankavatara Sutra exist anywhere online in Tibetan script, Sanskrit (Devanagari), or Chinese?

Tags: sutras, texts

Not sure what the *earliest* copy is we have of the [Lankavatara Sutra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chan_Buddhism#Lankavatara_Sutra), but wondering if it can be found online for free in **copy/pastable text format** (i.e. not PDF or image).

I am looking through [The Kangyur on Thlib](http://www.thlib.org/encyclopedias/literary/canons/kt/catalog.php#cat=d/k-1-4-1) but not finding it anywhere. Does it exist in the Kangyur even, is it [this](http://www.thlib.org/encyclopedias/literary/canons/kt/catalog.php#cat=d/0108)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Wikipedia there's a [Multilingual edition](http://www2.hf.uio.no/polyglotta/index.php?page=volume&vid=441), Bibliotheca Polyglotta, University of Oslo.
You can use its UI to select how much is displayed -- i.e. one sentence or one chapter at a time, or the whole text at once -- and which laanguages.
The Tibetan and Sanskrit versions are in Roman text, plus there seems to be three Chinese versions/editions, written using Chinese characters.

http://www.dsbcproject.org/ has machine-readable Sanskrit editions of various suttas, you could also try browsing there and/or writing to sanskrit@uwest.edu to ask them.
I think that Laṅkāvatāra Sūtra might be also known as the Saddharmalankavatarasutram.

You're right though that what I see online is mostly non-text image scans.

---

**Is my tibetan link correct do you know? http://www.thlib.org/encyclopedias/literary/canons/kt/catalog.php#cat=d/0108**

It might be -- see the "Non-Tibetan Title" -- but I can't read the Tibetan to confirm that.

Also here is a copy from the link you posted:

[image]

That more-or-less matches what [the Tohoku catalog](http://prajnaquest.fr/downloads/BookofDzyan/Tohoku%20Catalogue%20of%20Tibetan%20Buddhist%20Canons.pdf) says on page 25:

[image]

I say "more-or-less" because the page numbers match i.e. pages 56 through 191, however the section number is off by one (i.e. 108 instead of 107).

Comment: Is my tibetan link correct do you know? http://www.thlib.org/encyclopedias/literary/canons/kt/catalog.php#cat=d/0108

Comment: I edited the answer.